# C pointer/array syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, syntax

I know that the following two things are the same in c (because of offsets and arrays)

```
someArray[i]     //ith element of someArray
*(someArray + i) //ith element of someArray
```

However for structs, the same syntax doesn't seem to hold up very well...

```
someStruct[i]->*(someArray + j)   //compiler error
*(someStruct + i)->someArray[j]   //Also compiler error
```

Is there anyway to use the pointer/offset notation (the second one) to represent elements of a struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `someStruct` is an array of structs, and `someArray` is a struct member of array type, then either of these would be valid:

```
*(someStruct[i].someArray + j)
```

or

```
(*(someStruct + i)).someArray[j]
```

See e.g. http://ideone.com/UtLN2.

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, you are using the pointer resolution operator `->` when you should probably be using the member reference operator `.`

Assuming someStruct[] is an array of structs (not pointers):

```
*(someStruct[i].someArray + j)
(*(someStruct + i)).someArray[j]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, I suppose that you want to represent *fields* of a structure through some pointer/offset arithmetic.

There's a standard macro, `offsetof(type, field)` in `stddef.h` which yields the offset of the field `field` inside the structure or union type `type`.

For example, suppose `s` is of type `struct s*`, and `f` is a field in `struct s`. Then `*(s + offsetof(struct s, f))` is the same as `s->f`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

`*(someStruct[i]->someArray + j)`

`(*(someStruct + i))->someArray[j]`